# snapshotId for resolveConflict in Google Play Saved Games

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

How to get snapshot ID in Gogle Play Saved Games (I'm using the latest revision 27 of Google Play Services Library for Android)?

There is a method in `com.google.android.gms.games.snapshot.Snapshots`:

```
public abstract PendingResult<Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult> resolveConflict (GoogleApiClient apiClient, String conflictId, String snapshotId, SnapshotMetadataChange metadataChange, SnapshotContents snapshotContents)
```

I can't find methods like `getID()`or `getSnapshotID()`in `Snapshot/SnapshotMetadata/OpenSnapshotResult` interfaces.

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no direct way to find the ***snapshot_id*** of a snapshot but you can get it like this:

- Determine the Player_id (set to *me* if its current authenticated user) and make a GET request to retrieve a list of snapshots created by your application for the player corresponding to the player ID.

  ```
  GET https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/playerId/snapshots
  ```
- This will return the ***snapshot Resources*** in the items array.
- The items array will contain the following JSON data:

  {
    "kind": "games#snapshot",
    "id": string,
    "driveId": string,
    "uniqueName": string,
    "type": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "coverImage": {
      "kind": "games#snapshotImage",
      "width": integer,
      "height": integer,
      "mime_type": string,
      "url": string
    },
    "lastModifiedMillis": long,
    "durationMillis": long
  }
- The **"id"** value associated with this key will be the ***snapshot_id*** you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think it may work but is too complicated for my needs. So I decided to use automatic conflict resolution for now (RESOLUTION_POLICY_xxx). I hope Google will add a simple and convenient Java function like getSnapshotId in the future versions of their library.

Answer (score 2):

Getting snapshot ID for conflict resolution is actually pretty easy. Just call `snapshot.getMetadata().getSnapshotId()` on your snapshot and thats it.

Your resolution code may then look like this:

```
Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult openSnapshotResult; //Conflicting open result

final SnapshotContents resContent = openSnapshotResult.getResolutionSnapshotContents();
//Make resolution of conflicting snapshot contents
resContent.writeBytes(...);

final Snapshot snapshot = openSnapshotResult.getSnapshot();
final String snapshotID = snapshot.getMetadata().getSnapshotId(); //Here comes your snapshot ID
Games.Snapshots.resolveConflict(PlayClient, openSnapshotResult.getConflictId(), snapshotID, SnapshotMetadataChange.EMPTY_CHANGE, resContent);
```

It doen't matter if you take Id of base snapshot or conflicting snapshot. They are the same.